# JS : Regular expression in switch case

Tags: javascript

I try to test a specific string with a switch case and I find this code :

```
let prop = "date myData";
switch (true) {
          case /str/.test(prop) :
            console.log("tata");
            break;

          case /date/.test(prop):
            console.log("toto");
            break;

          case /enum/.test(prop) :
            console.log("titi");
            break
          default :
            console.log("Nada");
            break;
}
```

It works but it don't resolve my problem. I want to get specifically the string "date" for example. With nothing before and nothing after.

I this example, I want my console to display "Nada".

I don't know how to do that with this code. 
A solution ? :)

Comment: Why use regex if you want equality? Just use `prop == "date"` for that case

Comment: It's just an exemple. I don't want to test juste this string but a collection with lot of others string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either start and end signs in the regular expression

```
/^date$/
```

or a simple test with a string and equality

```
prop === 'date'
```

or

```
switch (prop) {
    case 'date':
        console.log('date');
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly my solution ! :D

Answer (score 1):

For what you have there a switch is not your first choice - also you are just comparing strings for equality - so an easier way would be the following

```js
let prop = "date myData";
let strings = {str: "tata", date: "toto", enum:"titi"}
let res = strings[prop] || "Nada";
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

To test for equality to multiple strings, either stack case statements like this:

```
switch (true) {
  case prop === "date":
  case prop === "param2":
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

Or test for inclusion in a static array:

```
switch (true) {
  case ["date", "param2"].includes(prop):
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

Although switching on `true` is probably not the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: You could switch on the `prop` variable. That's the right way I guess.